# Copying R8G8B8A8 image to R8G8B8

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert an R8G8B8A8 image to R8G8B8 image, what I get right now is an image, but with a lot of scan lines, I have byters per pixels is 4 bytes, 32bit.

The image buffer is of type unsigned char [width*height*4] that's the source and the destination is unsigned char [width*height*3].

```
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < (width*height); k++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
        {
            dst[i + b] = src[j + b];

        }
        i+=3;
        j+=4;
    }
```

Comment: And what is the problem you're having?

Comment: Depending on platform there may be easier ways to do this, I know Windows Imaging component will do this for you. I would imagine libpng would do similar things (a quick google search shows that `PNG_TRANSFORM_STRIP_ALPHA` is a thing)

Comment: @molbdnilo: It's slightly inefficient (extraneous loop condition, can be replaced by a check for either `i==3*width*height` or `j=4*width*height`. The code is technically correct assuming packed layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the destination image requires lines aligned on a 4 bytes boundary:

```
for(unsigned int y(0); y != height; ++y)
{
    unsigned int sourceStart(y * width * 4);
    unsigned int destStart(y * ((width * 3 + 3) & 0xfffffffc) ); // align on 4 bytes
    for(unsigned int x(0); x != width; ++x)
    {
        for(unsigned int color(0); color != 3; ++color)
        {
            dst[destStart++] = src[sourceStart++];
        }
        ++sourceStart; // account for 4th byte in source
    }
}
```

Comment: what I found is the source image is width 480 and height is 640, so the processing should be the reverse, correct ? or it doesn't matter ? and the dst image should be width 640 and height 480

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < width*height; k++)
{
    for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
    {
        dst[k*3 + b] = src[k*4 + b];

    }
}
```